# Can I connect RaspberryPi GPIO to Nintendo DS Buttons?

Tags: gpio

I was wondering if I can connect a Raspberry Pi to the buttons of a Nintendo DS. I have seen something similar on Youtube for the Switch controller. My goal is to control the buttons using a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can, if you want something easy to play with the GPIO I suggest you WiringPi, if you already worked on **Arduino** it's the same thing but on **raspberry**.

If i have well understood you you want to make the raspberry play for you ? Some sort of Rogue player?

For doing so you will have to understand the schematic of the button, is it a *pull-up* or *pull-down* *etc* ? Knowing that you will be able to know where you should connect the DS to the RSP. And don't forget to connect both ground. Thus you should keep in mind that the **raspberry's GPIO are 3.3V only**, so if the DS use **5V** you will have to use a **logical level converter**.